# Strip default CSS from Django CMS

Tags: css, django, django-cms

I noticed that the text rendered by Django CMS' text plug-in is hard-coded with its own CSS, the `p` tags in particular. Is there a way to remove this styling? I want the text to inherit the style specified in the theme I am using. There does not seem to be an option to do this in the GUI and there is no mention in the [docs for the text plug-in](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.5/getting_started/plugin_reference.html#text).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the template used by the text plugin](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/plugins/text/templates/cms/plugins/text.html) you'll notice that it simply renders the contents of TinyMCE (or whatever WYSIWYG editor you are using) so the markup you are seeing is likely from there, not the template.

You can override this template yourself by creating a `text.html` file in your templates folder (i.e `/templates/cms/plugins/text.html`) and adding a surrounding `div` :

```
<div class="cms-text-plugin">{{ body|safe }}</div>
```

now you can target the elements with CSS:

```
.cms-text-plugin p{ ... }
.cms-text-plugin h1{ ... }
```

Comment: Umm...this did not work. The `{{ body|safe }}` template  code renders HTML as: `<p style="wanna_strip_this">P1</p><p style="wanna_strip_this">P2</p>...`. Adding div tags as suggested wouldn't change the text's rendering since the style attribute of the p tags will still be more specific.

Comment: Those tags are particular to TinyMCE so this has nothing to do with Django. But you can absolutely target those `p` tags with your own custom CSS if you use an ID instead of class (as in the example) as it will have a higher specificity (or simply use `!important`)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the template for each CMS plugin by creating the same directory structure and file name in your templates directory. Then you can control the markup. This concept is the same as overriding any other template provided by a 3rd party in Django. It's just like overriding a template provided by admin, etc.